# Excel time conversion from words

Tags: excel

I was sent a spread sheet and it listed the times as "00 hours 04 minutes 44 seconds"   how do i convert 00 hours 04 minutes 44 seconds  into a regular time like 04:44 in excel?

Comment: What happened to the hours field? Do you want 00:04:44?

Comment: I guess it could have the hours field if that made it easier.  All of the hours would be 00 though because I only have minutes and seconds .  I am doing a project for school and I am looking at response times and then I have to create graphs and find out averages so I just need in a better format

Comment: Ah, so it's irrelevant. Well, the answer below should work if you ever need the hours.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, assuming your data is in cell A1:

`=RIGHT(LEFT(A1, FIND("hours", A1)-2), 2)&":"&RIGHT(LEFT(A1, FIND("minutes", A1)-2), 2)&":"&RIGHT(LEFT(A1, FIND("seconds", A1)-2), 2)`

You can see what each individual piece is doing if you split it apart at the `&`. For example, `=RIGHT(LEFT(A1, FIND("minutes", A1)-2), 2)` returns "04". One level in from that, `LEFT(A1, FIND("minutes", A1)-2)` returns "00 hours 04", and you need the right two characters of that.

This should work regardless of what order the hours, minutes, and seconds are in.

Comment: OMG!  How do people figure this stuff out!  You saved my day!  thank you so much!

Comment: How would I then sort that information from lowest number to highest?  the sort function does not sort anything it just keeps it the same.

Answer (score 1):

The CGritton's solution shows the time as text (you can not change the format or do some calculation with it).

If all cells have the same format ## hours ## minutes ## seconds you can simplify the formula.

Assuming that you have "00 hours 04 minutes 44 seconds" in cell B4, just type, for example in cell D4:

=TIME(LEFT(B4,2),MID(B4,10,2),MID(B4,21,2))

Then you can change the format to: hh:mm:ss AM/PM  or hh:mm AM/pm or hh:mm